# Prove $\bar{\Phi}^{-1}(\varepsilon) \sim \sqrt{2|\ln (\varepsilon)|}$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis

Let $\bar{\Phi}$ be the standard normal tail function defined by
$$
\bar{\Phi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{x}^{+\infty} e^{-u^{2} / 2} d u.
$$
Let $\bar{\Phi}^{-1}$ be its inverse.
Prove that $\bar{\Phi}^{-1}\left(\varepsilon\right)\sim\sqrt{2\left|\ln\left(\varepsilon\right)\right|}$.

---

We have
$$
\varepsilon=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\bar{\Phi}^{-1}\left(\varepsilon\right)}^\infty e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\,du.
$$
Then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I'd personally consider a subtraction from $1$, so that you don't need to deal with integrals at $\infty$. Furthermore, I think it is likely you'll want to do a series expansion

Comment: You want to invert the large-$x$ asymptotics of $\bar \Phi$.

Answer (score 1):

It is elementary to show $\Phi(x)=\frac{1+o(1)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}x^{-1}e^{-x^2/2}$. So letting $\Phi(x)=\varepsilon$ gives $x\sim \sqrt{2|\log\varepsilon|}$.